# Recyclerview ViewHolder is not clickable - android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView Viewholder click is not working. I am using LinearLayoutManager for the recyclerview. No clcik event is triggered inside recyclerview viewholder. Did I miss something, here is my ViewHolder

```
 public class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
            @Bind(R.id.imgNewUser)  CircularImageView imgUser;
            @Bind(R.id.txtUserNameNewUser)  TextView txtUserNameNewUser;
            @Bind(R.id.txtNewUserPostCount)  TextView txtNewUserPostCount;
            @Bind(R.id.btnFollowNewUser)  Button btnFollowNewUser;
            public FeedViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                view.setOnClickListener(this);
                ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
            }
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                onFollowListener.onFollow(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
```

And the inflated row layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnFollowNewUser"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.petmire.petmireapp.common.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgNewUser"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:border_width="0.5dp"
        app:border_color="@android:color/black"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUserNameNewUser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Petmireapp1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNewUserPostCount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="26 Posts"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFollowNewUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Follow"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_follow_shape"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Help me resolve this.

Comment: Refer here for Recycler view click http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: can't we handle onclick like what I have implemented? it is working for StaggeredGridLayoutManager but not for LinearLayoutManager

Comment: i had not verified for staggeredGridLayoutmanager yo can try and verify